# Search videos by exact length under Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows, video, windows-explorer, windows-search

is there a way to search videos by exact length under the Windows File Explorer? (i.e. length:00:31:42)

There is a command "length:" but it only supports values like "Very Short, Short, Medium, Long, Very Long".

Answer (score 2):

You can search for videos and other media files for specific `Length` (`System.Media.Duration`), but it's not as straightforward as you might have hoped. Property System Viewer reaveals that `Length` is stored as an unsigned 8-byte integer (`Uint64` in **PowerShell**).

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Display Name | Length |
| Viewable | Yes |
| Canonical Name | System.Media.Duration |
| Property Key | {64440490-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03},3 |
| Property Type | Unsigned Integer (8-Byte) |

This number is interpreted as a .Net **System.TimeSpan** structure. Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-7.0):

> The value of a TimeSpan object is the number of ticks that equal the represented time interval. A tick is equal to 100 nanoseconds, or one ten-millionth of a second. The value of a TimeSpan object can range from TimeSpan.MinValue to TimeSpan.MaxValue.

In **PowerShell**, you can convert the raw value (ticks) to a formatted string and vice-versa like so:

```
PS C:\> ([timespan]75553440000).ToString()
02:05:55.3440000
PS C:\>
PS C:\> [timespan]::Parse('02:05:55').Ticks
75550000000
```

Although the displayed `Length` changes in increments of seconds, the stored value is accurate to the nearest milllisecond, but they are truncated when the value is displayed. Thus, if you want to search for `00:00:01`, you actually have to specify a range from `00:00:01` to `00:00:01.999`
This bit of **PowerShell** compares the actual stored value to the value resulting from back-converting the displayed value to ticks:

```
gci $home\videos *.avi -s | %{
    $comFolder     = $shell.NameSpace((Split-Path $_.FullName))
    $DisplayTime   = $comFolder.GetDetailsOf($comFolder.ParseName(($_.Name)) , 27)
    $Exactticks    = $comFolder.ParseName(($_.Name)).ExtendedProperty("Duration")
    $ApproxTicks   = [TimeSpan]::Parse( $DisplayTime).Ticks
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Display Time' = $DisplayTime
        'Exact Ticks'  = $Exactticks
        'Approx Ticks' = $ApproxTicks
        'Difference'   = $Exactticks - $ApproxTicks
}} | sort difference
```

OUtput:

```
Display Time  Exact Ticks Approx Ticks Difference
------------  ----------- ------------ ----------
02:43:36      98160065306  98160000000      65306
02:43:36      98160240000  98160000000     240000

   ...            ...           ...          ...

02:58:12     106929120000 106920000000    9120000
02:33:40      92209920000  92200000000    9920000
```

The search criteria must be expressed in ticks, So to search for a file with a displayed Length of `1:53:24`:

```
PS C:\> ($LowBound  = [timespan]::Parse('1:53:24').Ticks)
68040000000
PS C:\> ($HighBound = ([timespan]$LowBound).Add([timespan]::Parse('0:0:0.999')).Ticks)
68049990000
PS C:\> ($SearchExpression = 'Length:>={0} AND <= {1}' -f $LowBound , $HighBound )
Length:>=68040000000 AND <= 68049990000
PS C:\> $SearchExpression | Set-Clipboard
```

Then, opening an **Explorer** window to my `Videos` folder, clicking in the Search box and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> yiels:

[image]

And executing the search returns the one video with the desired length:

[image]

---

Not knowing the details of youtr workflow, it's hard to guess how to make this as easy as possible. One way would be a **PowerShell** script that accepts `hh:mm:ss` input and executes the search in **Explorer**:

```
###   To keep example simple, the code assumes
###   there are no other **Explorer** windows open.

$shell        = New-Object -com shell.application
$SearchTarget = $shell.NameSpace("shell:My Video").Self.Path
$shell.Open($SearchTarget)
While ($shell.Windows().Count -eq 0) {sleep -m 25}
$TargetWin = @($shell.Windows())[0]
While ($true) {
    $SearchCriteria = Read-Host 'Enter length (hh:mm:ss)'
    $SpanTicks      = [timespan]::Parse($SearchCriteria).Ticks
    $FilterString   = 'Length:>= {0} <= {1}' -f $SpanTicks , ($SpanTicks + 9990000)
    $TargetWin.Document.FilterVIew($FilterString)
    $TargetWin.Visible = $true
}
```

---

### Edit: Improved script: Launch from window background, specify ranges as well as specific values, and muliple vales/ranges.

1. Save the following as a `.ps1` file.
2. Open a **PowerShell** window and run with dot-sourcing to install:

   ```
    . <path to .ps1 file>
   ```
3. `Search media by Duration` will now be available when right-clicking in the background of any file folder.

```
If ($Args) {   ###   Launched from directory background context menu
    $folderPath       = $Args[0]
    $shell            = New-Object -com shell.application
    $TargetWindow     = @($shell.Windows() | where $folderPath -eq $_.Document.Folder.Self.Path  )[0]

    Function Get-Filter {
        param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory)][Uint64]$ts1,
            [Parameter(Mandatory)][Uint64]$ts2
        )
        Process {
            '(>= {0} <= {1})' -f $ts1 , ($ts2 + 9990000)
        }
    }

    $Prompt           = @"
Enter one or more (comma-separated) criteria as either:
`ta Specific TimeSpan (delimiters optional): "hh[:| |-|.]mm[:| |-|.]ss"
`tor specify a range : "<lowerTimeSpan>..<upperTimeSpan>`n`n
"@

    $SearchCriteria   = Read-Host $Prompt

    $FilterText       = 'Length: ({0})' -f (($SearchCriteria -split '\s*\,\s*' | ForEach {
        Switch -Regex ($_) {
            '^(\d{2})[\:\ \.\-]?(\d{2})[\:\ \.\-]?(\d{2})$' {
                $Ticks    = [timespan]::Parse('{0}:{1}:{2}' -f $Matches[1..3]).Ticks
                $Filter   = Get-Filter $Ticks $Ticks
            }
            '^(\d{2})[\:\ \.\-]?(\d{2})[\:\ \.\-]?(\d{2})\.\.(\d{2})[\:\ \.\-]?(\d{2})[\:\ \.\-]?(\d{2})$' {
                $Ticks1   = [timespan]::Parse(('{0}:{1}:{2}' -f $Matches[1..3])).Ticks
                $Ticks2   = [timespan]::Parse(('{0}:{1}:{2}' -f $Matches[4..6])).Ticks
                $Filter   = Get-Filter $Ticks1 $Ticks2
            }
        }
        $Filter
    }) -join ' OR ' )

    If ($FilterText) {
        $TargetWindow.Document.FilterView($FilterText)
    }
} Else {   ###   Create context menu entry
    $Key   = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\Shell\SearchMediaByDuration'
    If (!(Test-Path $key)) {
        New-Item -Path $key -Value 'Search media by &Duration'
        $PSexe   = '%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass'
        $splat   = @{
            'Path'       = "$key\Command"
            'Value'      = ('{0} -File {1} "%V"' -f $PSexe , $PSCommandPath)
            'ItemType'   = 'ExpandString'
        }
        New-Item @splat
    }
}
```